# Error on Oracle Case statement assigning value

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I wanted to assign a value "F" to TBL_C.PAY_CODE when its value is T but I cant seem to find the error in this SQL statement. I don't want to use PL/SQL for this just normal SQL statement.

ERROR

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
```

SQL CODE

```
SELECT
    TBL_A.ACT_ID,
    TBL_A.ACT_CODE,
    TBL_A.ACT_DESC,
    TBL_A.ACT_DIS_DESC,
    TBL_B.ACTMAP_ID,
    TBL_B.CLI_ID 
FROM CACT TBL_A, CMACTM TBL_B, CMACTDM TBL_C 
WHERE TBL_A.ACT_ID=TBL_B.ACT_ID AND B.ACTMAP_ID=TBL_C.ACTMAP_ID 
AND TBL_C.CODE = 'Version64'
AND TBL_C.ID='100001000000001'
AND TBL_C.PAY_CODE= CASE
  WHEN TBL_C.PAY_CODE='T' AND TBL_C.CODE ='Version64'
  THEN TBL_C.PAY_CODE='F' <-- ERROR 
  else TBL_C.PAY_CODE='T'
  END;
```

## Update

This query is for retrieving one row which has the following table values. When users submit a button with the following values but with Pay_Code equal to T the row below should be retrieved. I cannot change the value of the pay_code because there are other problems that will be encountered.

Table TBL_C

```
ACTMAP_ID          ID                PAY_CODE  CODE
100001000000100    100001000000001   F         Version64
```

Original Query Used:

```
SELECT TBL_A.ACT_ID, TBL_A.ACT_CODE, TBL_A.ACT_DESC, TBL_A.ACT_DIS_DESC, TBL_B.ACTMAP_ID, TBL_B.CLI_ID 
    FROM CACT TBL_A, CMACTM TBL_B, CMACTDM TBL_C 
    WHERE TBL_A.ACT_ID=TBL_B.ACT_ID AND B.ACTMAP_ID=TBL_C.ACTMAP_ID 
    AND TBL_C.CODE =? (Value is Version64)
    AND TBL_C.ID=? (Value is 100001000000001)
    AND TBL_C.PAY_CODE=? (Either T or F but in the value is set to F)
```

Comment: ok, so any ideas how i could get to TBL_C.PAY_CODE to have a F value even when its value is T?

Comment: yes. see below for the correct syntax.

Comment: tnx Mitch i'll try the one you suggested

Comment: How can `TBL_C.PAY_CODE` equal both `T` and `F`?

Comment: I would try using `OR` rather than `Case` in the `Where` clause, but I can't determine your desired logic. Are you trying to return all records where `TBL_C.PAY_CODE='T'` and `TBL_C.CODE ='Version64'` or where `TBL_C.PAY_CODE='F'` and `TBL_C.CODE` is some other value than `'Version64'`?

Comment: Does the User input come in as a parameter or something?

Comment: Users choose T or F in dropdown menu. In Java DAO the we use prepareStatement so it appears like this tbl_c.pay_code=?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TBL_A.ACT_ID, TBL_A.ACT_CODE, TBL_A.ACT_DESC, TBL_A.ACT_DIS_DESC, TBL_B.ACTMAP_ID, TBL_B.CLI_ID 
FROM CACT TBL_A, CMACTM TBL_B, CMACTDM TBL_C 
WHERE TBL_A.ACT_ID=TBL_B.ACT_ID AND B.ACTMAP_ID=TBL_C.ACTMAP_ID 
AND TBL_C.CODE = 'Version64'
AND TBL_C.ID='100001000000001'
AND TBL_C.PAY_CODE= CASE
  WHEN TBL_C.PAY_CODE='T' AND TBL_C.CODE ='Version64'
  THEN 'F'    <-------------
  else 'T'    <-------------
  END;
```

Note: The fact you are comparing `TBL_C.CODE = 'Version64'` twice suggests a possible flaw in your logic....

Comment: @Ron Smith: your attempted edits add little or no value to the answer (or question)

Comment: hi mitch thanks for the tip, your suggestion got rid of the error but i can't retrieve any rows using this query i might tweak this a bit

Comment: see this bit:   TBL_C.CODE = 'Version64', it's there twice.

Comment: @Mitch, most would agree that formatting code for readability is of some value.

Comment: you'd be better off converting the non-ANSI join syntax!!  Normally I'd agree about readability but the error is clearly highlighted in my answer.

Comment: @Ron there was a change in business logic and apparently they don't want to add another column or add another type of value into that column as it requires alot of changes. So for that specific item its paycode is F but when users do a query they usually place T so it never shows up. Its the only solution i come up with in order for this row to be retrieved

Comment: the non-ANSI joins don't force the user to scroll to the right to read the script...

Comment: @dinas" rather than show your perceived solution, tell us the desired outcome of the query.

Comment: @Ron Smith : they affect the understandability.

Comment: And your answer doesn't address the fact that one of the `Cases` tries to return records where `TBL_C.PAY_CODE` is equal to both `T` and `F`...

Comment: Yes, actaully it does. See the NOte?  "The fact you are comparing TBL_C.CODE = 'Version64' twice suggests a possible flaw in your logic..." Pretty clear that.

Comment: Hi Mitch kindly see update and thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0):

Great question, dimas! I'm not clear on your desired logic, but it appears you want to return records where `BL_C.PAY_CODE='T'` and `TBL_C.CODE ='Version64'` or `BL_C.PAY_CODE='F'`. If this is the case, I would write it:

```
SELECT
    TBL_A.ACT_ID,
    TBL_A.ACT_CODE,
    TBL_A.ACT_DESC,
    TBL_A.ACT_DIS_DESC,
    TBL_B.ACTMAP_ID,
    TBL_B.CLI_ID 
FROM CACT TBL_A, CMACTM TBL_B, CMACTDM TBL_C 
WHERE TBL_A.ACT_ID=TBL_B.ACT_ID AND B.ACTMAP_ID=TBL_C.ACTMAP_ID 
AND TBL_C.ID='100001000000001'
AND ((TBL_C.PAY_CODE='T' AND TBL_C.CODE ='Version64')
    OR TBL_C.PAY_CODE='F');
```

If I have misread your desired outcome, please clarify and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hi Ron, kindly see update and thanks for the answer I actually tried the almost the same solution but can't get it to work.